# Gparted partition resize gone wrong - failed to read last sector

Tags: partitioning, ntfs, gparted, resize

I have tried to resize (shrink) my NTFS partition so that I will be able to get more space for my `ext4` Ubuntu's (12.04 64 bit) partition but after the partition has been resized I am unable to mount it. 
I used Gparted to do this.

I assume there is a problem somewhere with the partition table but I do not know where and how to fix it.

This is what I get in Gparted information window on NTFS partition:
[image]

GParted overview screenshot
[image]

`fdisk -l` and `mount /dev/sda5 /media/d`

```
root@UBUNTU:/home/XXX# mount /dev/sda5 /media/d
Failed to read last sector (718198764): Invalid argument
HINTS: Either the volume is a RAID/LDM but it wasn't setup yet,
   or it was not setup correctly (e.g. by not using mdadm --build ...),
   or a wrong device is tried to be mounted,
   or the partition table is corrupt (partition is smaller than NTFS),
   or the NTFS boot sector is corrupt (NTFS size is not valid).
Failed to mount '/dev/sda5': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sda5' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
root@UBUNTU:/home/XXX# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x68beefda

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1              19    27262991    13631486+  27  Hidden NTFS WinRE
/dev/sda2   *    27262992    27467791      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3        27467792   232267775   102399992    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       232267793   976771071   372251639+   f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       232267795   918867967   343300086+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6       968046592   976771071     4362240   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda7       950468608   968044543     8787968   83  Linux

Partition table entries are not in disk order
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After few minutes of digging I have found [this guide](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/fix-corrupted-windows-ntfs-filesystem-ubuntu/) which uses `ntfs-3g` package to recover broken ntfs partition.

Great tool! I can recommend it to everyone.

Comment: Great! ntfsfix seems to at least get my Windows partition booted into chkdsk and is now busy trying to fix the disk.

Comment: This worked for me on UNRAID that uses slackware when I tried to mount a Windows drive. The command I used to mount was `mount -t ntfs-3g -o fmask=133,dmask=022,gid=users,uid=1000 /dev/sdg1 /mnt/disks/2TB_SATA`

Answer (score 2):

This did the job for me:

sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda1

Where sda1 is the NTFS partition with the issue.

After that command and next restart into windows, it will check the disk and things will work fine again.